# InRelease The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG C45B1676A04EA552, trying to install Nvidia-Docker2 in tesla t4

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, ubuntu-18.04

Trying to install Nvidia-docker2 on a system with Tesla T4 GPU on a Ubuntu 18.04 server.  However, when I attempt to perform an apt-get update, i get the following error.

[image]

---

I am trying to install docker2, with this [article](https://medium.com/@sh.tsang/docker-tutorial-5-nvidia-docker-2-0-installation-in-ubuntu-18-04-cb80f17cac65)

sudo apt-get install nvidia-docker2
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-docker2

Comment: You have to reduce your system's security in order to install something that is unsigned.  Have you done that per the message you received in your screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure you fetched the latest GPG key from the repositories.
>
> https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/837#issuecomment-427560945